# Android Reflection on Cast and listener

Tags: android, reflection

I have a application with minsdk=4

I would like to use the calendarview class , on devices that support this (api>=11)
I prefer reflection above wrapper class , so that i don't have to increase build api level.
This prevents accidentally using new functions and creating errors.

This is part of my code.

```
    CalendarView cv = (CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calview);
    cv.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year,
                int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            ....
            ....
```

I can't manage to get this right.
Keep finding reflection hard to get..

thxs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of have a solution.

My main concern with wrapper class was that , accidentally using new api's would not be marked as a error..and so i could easily introduce new bug into my app.

But since ADT 17 , lintcheck has a check for this.

See: [lintapicheck](http://tools.android.com/recent/lintapicheck)

Note. it does not automatic on my eclipse install (even with both checkboxes run on save and export enabled)
I have to right click my project , android-tools -> run lint.

This is a good solution for me , so i will happily say goodbye to reflection from here on.

Comment: to supress layout errors add :        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:ignore="NewApi" to xml element